# How can I create an Excel table from Power Query WITH the data connection not just the table

Tags: vba, powerquery

## Can anyone help with how to create a table from a Power Query and make sure that the connection is created with it?

`I can create the table but there is not connection along with it, which means that anytime I need to refresh the data, it will refresh to PQ and is visible in the Editor but it will not refresh to the Excel table. Grrr

Right at the bottom I have been slashing about trying to create a connection but to no avail ...
`

````
> ```
> Sub LoopToCreateTest() ' LoopToCreateSheetsAndTablesFromQueries
>        'declare a variant array
> 
> Dim ws As Worksheet
> 
>        'populate the array
> On Error Resume Next
> 
> Qnames = Array("PrePayments")
> 
> 
> 
>        'loop through the entire array
> For Each item In Qnames 'strNames
> Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
> ActiveSheet.name = item
> Range("H1") = item ' Put a title on the page
> Range("H1").Select
> 
> With Selection.Font
>                 .name = "Calibri"
>                 .Size = 22
>                 .Strikethrough = False
>                 .Superscript = False
>                 .Subscript = False
>                 .OutlineFont = False
>                 .Shadow = False
>                 .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
>                 .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
>                 .TintAndShade = 0
>                 .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
> End With
> Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
> 
> ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 9 '3=Red , 4=green,5=blue,6=yellow,etc...
>  
> Create the tables from the list of queries
> 
> With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
>         "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & item & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
> Destination:=Range("$b$5")).QueryTable
>         .CommandType = xlCmdSql
>         .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & item & "]") ' this is where you need to concatenate the array value name
>         .RowNumbers = False
>         .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
>         .PreserveFormatting = False
>         .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
>         .BackgroundQuery = True
>         .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
>         .SavePassword = False
>         .SaveData = True
>         .AdjustColumnWidth = False
>         .RefreshPeriod = 0
>         .PreserveColumnInfo = False
>         .ListObject.DisplayName = "tabl"  ' this doesn't need concatenating
>         .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
> 
> 
> 
> End With
> Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
> 
> Create connections between the queries and the tables, without which the tables will not refresh even             though the data is in PQ
> With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection")
>         .name = item
>         .Description = "Connection for " & item & " query in Power Query"
> 
> End With
> 
> 
> Next item
> 
> End Sub
````

> 

1. Tried the code above
2. Converted it back to connection only and then reloaded manually to a table and it worked fine ..
3. If I recreate it after changing source data, it does pick up the change

Comment: You might want to tag this as VBA

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding something. But I generated VBA code for a Power Query by recording a Macro including a "Close and Load To` step. The generated code **was** connected to the output table. And if I made a change in the Source table, and then refreshed the query, the output table was updated.

Comment: Thanks both for coming back to me.  sorry for the delay.  I may have been having a moment, or it may be been our intern file synch at the heart of this issue.

Comment: gosh .. so dim here - how do I tag this as VBA ?

Comment: @user1389913 Did it for you

Comment: I have a bigger update on this also.  Should I edit the original post or add an answer ?

Comment: @user1389913 1. `edit tags` 2. edit original